# Проект крашится после установки

Tags: c#, wpf, install

Проблема следующая: создан проект wpf (с использованием фреймов и страниц). В отладке все стабильно работает, но после установки запускается только главное меню, а при переходе на следующую страницу проект крашится. Не понимаю почему так происходит. Есть только одна идея: не верно указал пути к картинкам и звукам.

Переход между страницами:

```
var MainMenuPage = new ViewMainMenu();
MainFrame.Navigate(MainMenuPage);
```

Пример подключения звука:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri(@"..\..\Телефон - Гудки.mp3", UriKind.Relative)); player.Play();
```

Пример подключения картинок:

```
friend_call_image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/FriendCall.png"));
```

Пример подключения текстового файла:

```
string readpath = @"..\..\Questions.txt"; // путь к файлу с вопросами
```

Подключал все по разному, т.к. не находил другого рабочего способа.

Comment: Добавляйте в проект логирование и показывайте сообщение об ошибке, стектрейс и прочее. Без этого бесполезно что-то советовать, проблема вообще может быть не в том месте, где вы предполагаете...

Comment: Программа ваша крашится ведь с каким-то сообщением? Что там написано? Если вы предполагаете причину, то закомментируйте сомнительные места, пересоберите проект и проверьте снова, может причина совсем в другом месте?